Incompatibility of the '\onslide' environment with environments that have a running counter
I'm using the following custom environment for theorems:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcounter{boxedthmcounter}
\newenvironment{boxedthm}{%
\refstepcounter{boxedthmcounter}%
\begin{mdframed} 
[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black,backgroundcolor=gray!10,roundcorner=5pt]
    \textbf{Theorem \theboxedthmcounter.}
}{%
\end{mdframed}
}

The above environment does not work well with the \onslide environment. When running:
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text that appears on all overlays.
\onslide<2->
\begin{boxedthm}
A theorem that appears in a transparent mode on overlay one and appears in a normal mode from overlay 2 onwards. 
\end{boxedthm}
\end{document}

The theorem gets number 1 on slide number 1 and then its numbering changes to two in the second slide/build. I want its numbering to be fixed through all builds.
Using the \only environment instead of \onslide fixes the problem. However, the \only environment is not compatible with \setbeamercovered{transparent}.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

This is a reasonable request. Many thanks!

If one puzzles together your code fragments, the code does not compile.

You could use \resetcounteronoverlays{boxedthmcounter} to add your counter to the list of counters which get reset at the start of an overlay:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcounter{boxedthmcounter}
\newenvironment<>{boxedthm}{%
\begin{uncoverenv}#1
\refstepcounter{boxedthmcounter}%
\begin{mdframed} 
[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=black,backgroundcolor=gray!10,roundcorner=5pt]
    \textbf{Theorem \theboxedthmcounter.}
}{%
\end{mdframed}
\end{uncoverenv}
}

\resetcounteronoverlays{boxedthmcounter}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text that appears on all overlays.
\begin{boxedthm}<2->
A theorem that appears in a transparent mode on overlay one and appears in a normal mode from overlay 2 onwards. 
\end{boxedthm}
\end{frame}


\end{document}



It worked perfectly! Many thanks :)

@Saleh You're welcome!
